# Using requirejs with createpool - Write mysql data to HMTL

Tags: mysql, requirejs, require

I'm trying to write data of a mysql database to a HTML file (website). I have one HTML file and one script (music_explorer.js) that is declared in the HTML file.

I was using this for connecting the database with the client-side:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
document.getElementById("sql").innerHTML = "Nuevo SQL externo";
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "isabelrodriguez",
  password: "francia",
  database: "WORLD",
  port : "3306"
})
```

I didn't have problems connecting the database and fetching data by running the script using the terminal (commmand:  > node .\music_explorer.js).

Then I run the HTML file that has the script declared inside. But, I got this error for the require function:

`Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I looked for this error and I found that "require" function can't be used in a browser enviroment so I change the code using requirejs, like this:

```
var mysql = requirejs(['../node_modules/mysql']);
document.getElementById("sql").innerHTML = "Nuevo SQL externo";
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "isabelrodriguez",
  password: "francia",
  database: "WORLD",
  port : "3306"
})
```

I solve the previous error of "require" function but now I get this error for createPool:

`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: mysql.createPool is not a function`

I supposed that this is because "requirejs" doesn't work like "require" function, but how can I solve this? Please help.

My script has more code besides of the mysql part, I have to work it in a external file.

I would appreciate a lot if anyone can help me! Thanks in advance.

Rolando

What I'm trying to do is: Using a mysql database for storing and then write data to a website using javascript. I connected the database with visual studio code, I tried to fetch data running the HTML file and get an error for a function, I solved it changing the function and now I get another error.